# div's height 80% of parent's width?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I would like to assign to a div's height the 80% of the parent width.

Ideally something like:

```
foo {
    height: 80%width;
}
```

Comment: note for the duplicate: a block element will by default have its width equal to parent width (if we omit any margin/padding/border) so the question is to make height based on width for the same element which is maitaining an aspect ratio

Answer (score 1):

It's funny you should ask this because the default browser behavior, before flexbox was just that, height % units were based off the width of the parent block-level element by default.

We could work around it as per the following example & use padding-bottom ( %-units of which will be based off the parent element's width) with position:relative & then absolute-position a container inside of that to accomplish the layout logic you've asked for

```html
<div style="width:300px; height:250px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
  <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 50%; background: #ccc">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; border: 1px solid #000">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

& here's an example with the css extracted from the html

```css
.outter {
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.inner-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
   <div class="outter">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner-inner">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, although I prefer admcfajn's way of using the padding-height.  This uses the img tags ability to autoscale to force the container height to be 80% of the width.  The png in the img is a 5x4 transparent image which is autoscaled up to 100% width, and 80% height.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.container > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
}
.container > .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' style='width:300px'>
  <img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAECAYAAABGM/VAAAAAD0lEQVQYV2NkwAIYKRMEAAEmAAUCYu5+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' />
  <div class='content'>
  Boo
  </div>
</div>
```